# PHP - how to track all functon calls in eclipse (PDT)?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I am using eclipse PDT for my project development in PHP.

I want to make changes in some functions in existing project. So I need to trace at how many places the function is been called.

Is there any way I do this in Eclipse PDT ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: find in files or refactor menu options. I don't use eclipse but these are pretty standard terms for any IDE.

Comment: @jeff: **Refactor** worked for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Use something other than Eclipse. :)  It's about the worst of the options available for PHP development.  Both PHPStorm and NetBeans PHP support debugging with xdebug that will let you trace execution, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open file in eclipse and follow steps

1. Select function and right click on function
2. Select Refactor->Rename from menu
3. Now info box will appear, click down arrow for menu.
4. From menu click "Open rename dialog"
5. Rename function and click preview in dialog box

Now you can see in **Changes to be performed** section in dialog box, where the function is been called.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on function name -> references -> project.